# How can I add a Code Style for JSP in Intellij (v15 Community Edition)?

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to have formatting for my JSP files.  Under Code Style I only see: Java, Groovy, HTML, JSON, Kotlin, Properties, XML, and "Other File Types".  Where can I add JSP as a Code Style?  The JetBrains docs are not helpful.

[image]

I'm using 15.0.1 Community Edition.

Comment: What version of IntelliJ are you using? I'm seeing code style settings for JSPs in my IntelliJ Ultimate. If you are using Community edition, then that might be the reason why it's not available.

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt Good question, added above.

Comment: I'm afraid that JSP support is not available in Community edition, see [comparison matrix](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) for details. There might possibly be some support via third party plugins, but I'm not sure about that

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt if you add as an answer I will accept it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSP support is not included in Community edition of IntelliJ IDEA. To get support for JSP and other Java EE technologies and frameworks you must upgrade to the Ultimate edition.

Source: [Comparison matrix](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html)

Comment: I am not able to find JSP support in the Ultimate edition also.